# Is there any maximum length of character regex can handle?

Tags: regex, python-3.x

I'm stack in making my regex work in Python3.5.
I have a list which contains a lot of URLs.
Some URLs are short, others are long.

I could excerpt URLs I wanted...mostly but only this URL cannot be excerpted.

> http://www.forbes.com/sites/julianmitchell/2016/09/27/this-startup-uses-drones-to-map-and-manage-massive-construction-projects/#1ca4d634334e

Here is the code.

```
urlList=[]  # Assume there are many URLs in this list. 

interdrone = re.compile(r"http://www.interdrone.com/news/(?:.*)")
hp = re.compile(r"http://www.interdrone.com/$")

restOfThem=re.compile(r'\#|youtube|bzmedia|facebook|twitter|mailto|geoconnexion.com|linkedin|gplus|resources\.sdtimes\.com|precisionagvision')


cleanuplist =[] # Adding URLs I need to this new list.

for i in range(0,len(urlList)):
    if restOfThem.findall(ursList[i]):
        continue

    elif hp.findall(urlList[i]):
        continue

    elif interdrone.findall(urlList[i]):
        cleanuplist.append(urlList[i])

    else:
        cleanuplist.append(urlList[i])

logmsg("Generated Interdrone clean URL list")
return (cleanuplist)
```

forbes.com URL should fall into "else:" clause, so it should be added to cleanuplist. However, it is not. Again, only this one is not added to the new list.

I tried to pick specifically Forbes site by this,

```
forbes = re.compile(r"http://www.forbes.com/(?:.*)")
```

then, add following elif statement.

```
elif forbes.findall(urlList[i]):
    cleanuplist.append(urlList[i])
```

However, it also does not pick up forbes site.

Therefore, I come to doubt there is some kind of maximum boundary of character to apply regex (so that findall is skipped?). 
I could be wrong. How can I excerpt forbes.com site above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regex matches the URL you provided, specifically the `#` that's present in the last part of your URL. That's why it is skipped. There is no "character limit" (unless Python runs out of memory).

You need to be more restrictive with the regex. For example, what if your URL had been `http://www.forbes.com/sites/julianmitchell/2016/09/27/twitter-stock-down` - should it have matched the `twitter` part of your regex?

Also, you probably want to use `re.search()`, not `re.findall()`.

Furthermore, you don't seem to need the last `elif` clause since the same thing will happen whether it's true or not.

Lastly, the correct way to iterate would be `for url in urlList:` instead of using indexes. This is Python, not Java.

Comment: Another set of eyes helped me a lot... Thank you very much!